# '.Find'/'.FindNext' finding same cell repeatedly or returns error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of medical terms (Column F) and their associated numerical codes (Column G), and I need to find the medical term from Column F IN the list in Column B and put that term's associated code in Column C.

An image of a simplified version of my spreadsheet:

[image: simplified version of my spreadsheet]

what I want the spreadsheet to look like after the code is run:

[image: after the code is run]

My problem here is getting the code to find the next match within the list. The example I have in the images is for the medical term: `abnormal gait`. You can see that there are two matches in Column B (the first and last cells). The code I have for this is modified from the examples from [Microsoft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7426T.png) and [this other website that many of the forums have been recommending as a resource][3]. However, no matter how many times I try to modify the second 'find' command I always end up with one of these errors:

1. Unable to get the FindNext Property of the Range Class
2. Type Mismatch Error
3. The Find function repeatedly finds the same cell
4. The Find function finds the first cell, but it never finds the next cell and exits via End If.

   ```
   Sub Match2Cohort()
   Dim Phenotype, FindMe, FoundinList As Range
   Dim LRp, LastRow, i As Long
   Dim FirstMatch As String

   LRp = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
   LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
   Set Phenotype = Range("B1:b" & LRp)
   Set Terms = Range("F1:f" & LastRow)

   For i = 18 To LastRow
       FindMe = Cells(i, 6).Value
       Set FoundinList = Phenotype.Cells.Find(What:=FindMe, LookAt:=xlWhole)
       On Error Resume Next

       If Not FoundinList Is Nothing Then
           FirstMatch = FoundinList.Row
           Do
   'This loop allows me to combine multiple medical codes into the same cell.                    
               If IsEmpty(FoundinList.Offset(0, 1)) = True Then
                       FoundinList.Offset(0, 1) = Cells(i, 7).Value
               Else: FoundinList.Offset(0, 1) = FoundinList.Offset(0, 1).Value & "/" & Cells(i, 7).Value
               FoundinList.Offset(0, 1).Select
               End If

   'This is the code that is not working and all of the variations I've tried:
       With Phenotype
           Set FoundinList = .FindNext(FindMe)
           Set FoundinList = .FindNext(FindMe, After:=ActiveCell)
           Set FoundinList = .FindNext(After:=ActiveCell)
       End With

           Set FoundinList = Phenotype.FindNext(What:=FindMe, After:=ActiveCell, LookAt:=xlWhole)
           Set FoundinList = Phenotype.Find(What:=FindMe, After:=ActiveCell, LookAt:=xlWhole)
           Set FoundinList = Phenotype.FindNext(After:=FoundinList)
           Set FoundinList = Phenotype.FindNext(What:=FindMe, After:=FoundinList, LookAt:=xlWhole)
           Set FoundinList = Phenotype.Find(What:=FindMe, After:=FoundinList, LookAt:=xlWhole)

           Loop While FirstMatch <> FoundinList.Row
       End If
   Next i

   End Sub
   ```

At this point I have tried everything I can think of and everything I have found online, and just don't know what to try next.

Comment: I have tried using these websites that other posts within forums have reccommended but while I modeled my vba after them, the information contained within the posts isn't helping.

Comment: FirstMatch is defined as a string, while FoundInList.Row is a number - so "1" will not equal 1.   I think `Loop While FirstMatch <> FoundinList.Row` should be `Loop While Not FoundinList Is Nothing AND FirstMatch <> FoundinList.Row`

Comment: I tried adding "Not FoundinList Is Nothing" to the "loop while" statement but that didn't affect anything. I just removed the "Dim FirstMatch as String" and that didn't affect anything either. After it finds the first match it stops the loop and goes straight to "End If"

Comment: Don't remove the `Dim FirstMatch as String`  change it to `Dim FirstMatch as Long`.  Also PhenoType, FindMe, LRP and LastRow are Variants - you need to declare the type of each variable.  `Dim PhenoType As Range, FindMe As Range, etc`.

Comment: Is LastRow in your loop less than 18?  If it is then it will skip straight to the End If.

Comment: Are you dead set on using the `.Find` and `.FindNext` methods? This problem can be solved more efficiently both in terms of execution speed and amount of code required by using VBA arrays instead.

Comment: I am not dead set on using .Find if there is a different method that works. I am new to VBA (just started using it last week) so I was just going with what formulas I could easily understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an efficient solution to your problem that does not use the `.Find` or `.FindNext` methods.

```
Sub Match2Cohort()
    Dim i&, k&, TTmp$, PTmp$, p, t
    t = [f1].CurrentRegion.Resize(, 2)
    With ActiveSheet
        p = [b1].Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row, 2)
    End With
    For i = 1 To UBound(t)
        TTmp = LCase$(Replace(t(i, 1), " ", ""))
        For k = 1 To UBound(p)
            PTmp = "," & LCase$(Replace(p(k, 1), " ", "")) & ","
            If InStr(PTmp, "," & TTmp & ",") Then
                PTmp = p(k, 2) & "/" & t(i, 2)
                If Left$(PTmp, 1) = "/" Then PTmp = Mid$(PTmp, 2)
                p(k, 2) = PTmp
            End If
        Next
    Next
    [b1].Resize(UBound(p), UBound(p, 2)) = p
End Sub
```

Comment: The output of my answer is identical to the output of the answer you selected (once that answer has been fixed with Scott's suggestion). I asked if you were dead set on using this method before I invested the time to help you learn something better. Can you help me understand your decision process, please?

Comment: When I run this macro the data from Column A (which I didn't show here due to confidentiality issues) duplicates itself, shifting ColumnB to ColumnC. Since this macro didn't work when I tried it, but the other one did, I chose that answer.

Comment: Well, that's the reason... you did not not show or mention column A. Assumption was that it was blank. I have updated my answer. It ignores column A now. This is a 100 times more efficient than using the Find methods. Please reconsider your choice of answer.

Comment: That did run a lot faster. The only problem I am running into now (which I discovered this morning) is that some of the terms in Column F are acronyms which show up in unrelated words in Column B (e.g. "RP" shows up in "morphology" -- which is present in 110+ cells in Column B). Do you know of a way to restrict the 'finding' of the term to the whole word, but allow it the flexibility to find the term within a string of terms in the same cell?

Comment: I am willing to sort that out for you, but it's a little unclear. Is there any chance you can send me a small sample workbook that demonstrates the problem? My email address is:    daniel.ferry@gmail.com

Comment: I have updated once again. I think this solves the issue with the acronyms. Please give it a go and let me know.

Comment: OK. Please try it one more time. I have updated the answer again.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're trying to write:

```
Sub Match2Cohort()

    Dim Phenotype As Range, FindMe As String, FoundinList As Range
    Dim LRp As Long, LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim FirstMatch As String
    Dim Terms As Range

    LRp = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Phenotype = Range("B1:B" & LRp)
    Set Terms = Range("F1:F" & LastRow)

    For i = 18 To LastRow
        FindMe = Cells(i, 6).Value2

        'Find first occurrence.
        Set FoundinList = Phenotype.Cells.Find( _
            What:=FindMe, _
            After:=Phenotype.Cells(1), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext)

        If Not FoundinList Is Nothing Then
            FirstMatch = FoundinList.Address
            Do
                If IsEmpty(FoundinList.Offset(0, 1)) Then 'No need for "=TRUE" as the statement returns TRUE/FALSE
                    FoundinList.Offset(0, 1) = Cells(i, 7).Value
                Else
                    FoundinList.Offset(0, 1) = FoundinList.Offset(0, 1).Value & "/" & Cells(i, 7).Value
                End If

                Set FoundinList = Phenotype.FindNext(FoundinList)
            Loop While Not FoundinList Is Nothing And FirstMatch <> FoundinList.Address
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I think `LookAt:=xlWhole` needs to be `LookAt:=xlPart` no? based on the multiple conditions in each cell?

Comment: Thanks both of you! @ScottHoltzman. The code you provided worked perfectly once I changed `LookAt:=xlWhole` to `LookAt:=xlPart`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i think the best solution is to move away from FIND() and use strings.split, and application.index and application.match

Here's the logic:

Loop 1 'loop through cells in column B

Split the cells text at the comma and place in an array

Loop 2 ' loop through individual Phenotype array

Use application.match to find the term and code in columns F:G

Add the code to the cell in column C.

And here is the code:

```
Sub Text_Loop()
Dim i As Integer
Dim RngF as Range, RngB As Range
Dim mycell As Range
Dim phenoString() As String
Dim phenoCode As Variant

Set RngB = Sheet1.Range("b2:b" & Sheet1.Range("b2").End(xlDown).Row)
Set RngF = Sheet1.Range("F2:F" & Sheet1.Range("F2").End(xlDown).Row)

For Each mycell In RngB 'first loop
    phenoString = Split(mycell.Value, ",")

    For i = LBound(phenoString) To UBound(phenoString) 'second loop
        phenoCode = Application.Index(Sheet1.Range("F2:G" & Sheet1.Range("F2").End(xlDown).Row), _
            Application.Match(phenoString(i), RngF, 0), 2) 'use variant so that we can check for an error

        If WorksheetFunction.IsError(phenoCode) = False Then 'checks to make sure phenocode was found
            If mycell.Offset(0, 1) <> "" Then 'formats multiple phenotype codes with / in correct place
                mycell.Offset(0, 1) = mycell.Offset(0, 1) & "/" & phenoCode
            Else
                mycell.Offset(0, 1) = phenoCode
            End If
        End If

    Next i 'end first loop
Next mycell 'end second loop


End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim i As Integer` is dangerous as a practice when `i` will be used as an iterator, because the variable can easily overflow (though it won't in this case). In addition Integers are slightly slower than Longs, so unless the situation has a special need (like an API call that requires and INT16) there are only downsides to using Integers. In modern computing, the memory saved is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

For the life of me I cannot remember the 'simple' solution, but I am sure I have found in the past there was a setting within Excel that stopped the ".FindNext" working - I am having the issue now, with the loop just returning the same cell/row even though it will keep going until c is nothing???  (This results in many rows with the same data pasted each time.)

I just came up with another solution, a loop that includes resetting the search range, so each time it searches from the row after the last result.

I am using this to find rows with a specified person's name from a list (with other people listed) and to copy those rows to a sheet for the named person.  In other words, to isolate rows for a specific person from a larger list.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Refresh List of Dockets for selected Staff
If Range("A1") = "" Then Exit Sub

If MsgBox("Refresh Docket List for " & Range("A1") & "?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Please Confirm") <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim myRow, Rng1, Rng2
myRow = 4
Range("A4:G9999").Clear
Rng1 = "D2:D9999"
Do
    With Sheets("Master").Range(Rng1)
        Set c = .Find(Range("A1"), searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            Rng2 = "A" & c.Row & ":G" & c.Row
            Sheets("Master").Range(Rng2).Copy Range("A" & myRow)
            myRow = myRow + 1
            Rng1 = "D" & c.Row + 1 & ":D9999"
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    End With
Loop

Range("A1").Select
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1

End Sub
```